# Referencing another pages DataTable?

Tags: jquery, reference

apologies, new to JQuery and can't seem to find this anywhere (possibly not searching with correct terminology). I think what I'm doing 'may' be more complex than I imagined!

I was adding rows to a Data table within the same page using JQueries plug in - DataTables. Which works fine. I instead decided to do this from a separate page. So the addingRows.html is in a separate page to the table itself. I have this working to an extent, opening the new page etc. But my code seems to be falling over on the below, because it doesn't know where that listTable is anymore? How do I reference the listTable.html's listTable now? Or should I be doing this as some form of child page?

listTable.html

```
 <script>

     var lt = $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#listTable').DataTable;
       $('#addbtn').click(addToRow);
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: on the page where you execute the provided code, does the relevant markup (ie. `#listTable`) exist?

Comment: Sorry! I possibly wasn't clear. What I'm saying is, that listTable does not exist on that page anymore. How do I reference the listTable in the other page. Part of the confusion may be that listTable is the table and html name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work - each page is isolated from other pages, otherwise you would have a  major security issue - for example the hack site that you have open in one tab could grab your bank account details from another tab...

One alternative might be to use something like jQuery UI Tabs to include both bits of content onto a single page, but with visual separation.

Comment: Right! well that'll explain why i couldn't find anything on this! Thanks a lot. I will take a look into the UI tabs.